# How can I send byte commands via bluetooth to the serial port of a lego mindstorms EV3 using c++?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Using C++, how would I go about sending commands to my EV3/nxt from a machine that isn't running lego software? I'd like to control the forward, backward, left, and right directions of my mindstorms robot. Can I load the brick to respond to certain byte commands and then just send those byte commands via bluetooth from that different machine?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Here is some c# code I'm running on my EV3. I'm just trying to figure out how I could load this same functionality onto my brick and then trigger it via some byte commands like those in this [documentation](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/directcommands.html).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Lego.Ev3.Core;
using Lego.Ev3.Desktop;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace legoAPIDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Brick _brick;
        int _forward = 40;
        int _backward = -30;
        uint _time = 300;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _brick = new Brick(new BluetoothCommunication("COM3"));
            _brick.BrickChanged += _brick_BrickChanged;
            await _brick.ConnectAsync();
            await _brick.DirectCommand.PlayToneAsync(100, 1000, 300);
            await _brick.DirectCommand.SetMotorPolarity(OutputPort.B | OutputPort.C, Polarity.Backward);
            await _brick.DirectCommand.StopMotorAsync(OutputPort.All, false);
        }

        private void _brick_BrickChanged(object sender, BrickChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("BRICK CHANGED!"); 
        }

        private async void ForwardButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await _brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(OutputPort.B | OutputPort.C, _forward, _time, false);
        }

        private async void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await _brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(OutputPort.B | OutputPort.C, _backward, _time, false);
        }

        private async void LeftButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _brick.BatchCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTime(OutputPort.B, _backward, _time, false);
            _brick.BatchCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTime(OutputPort.C, _forward, _time, false);
            await _brick.BatchCommand.SendCommandAsync();
        }

        private async void RightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            _brick.BatchCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTime(OutputPort.C, _forward, _time, false);
            _brick.BatchCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTime(OutputPort.B, _backward, _time, false);
            await _brick.BatchCommand.SendCommandAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a C++ guy, so I can't really give a complete answer, but there is a very basic sample as part of the question at http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4256/cant-send-multiple-commands-to-ev3-using-python.

Comment: Hey thanks @DavidLechner, that's definitely along the lines of what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can check the source code of [ev3duder](https://github.com/c4ev3/ev3duder) or use its `tunnel` command and read/write the pipes.